# gunicorn memory usage increases high on AWS while a simple rest service is used

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

We have hosted our Web App **(Angular CLI: 1.7.3, Node: 9.5.0, Django 2.0.3)** on AWS free tier of **Ubuntu(14.04.5 LTS)** VM. We are using ELB (Elastic Load Balancers) with **Nginx-1.4.6** and **gunicorn-19.7.1**

When we try to use access our App from a browser then suddenly gunicorn memory usage increases quite high:

```
Normal:
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16248 ubuntu    20   0  313.1m  94.6m   9.3m R 15.6  9.5   0:00.71 gunicorn

While using App:
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16235 ubuntu    20   0  684.9m 315.8m  11.1m R 61.4 31.8   0:04.51 gunicorn
```

Below is our gunicorn configuration (/etc/init/gunicorn.conf):

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/project/

#--max-requests INT : will restarted worker after those many requests which can
#overcome any memory leaks in code
exec ./env/bin/gunicorn --max-requests 1 --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/home/ubuntu/project/django-ng.sock config.wsgi:application
```

We have already set **max-requests as 1 and workers as 3**. Could someone please tell what is going wrong?

Comment: In the local environment, everything works fine?

Comment: In local environment we are using "python3 manage.py runserver" for django and "ng serve" for Angular app and we are facing no issues. I mean python3 taking same memory or little increase if load increases which says that code looks fine (no memory leaks).

Comment: We are also having the same issue, @SatendraPratap did you found any solution.